# How to form single row data with incremented numbers using LISTTAG in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

**Column** 
ABC 
DEF 
GHI

The expected result is in a single row with bullet numbers as separation:

1. ABC 2. DEF 3. GHI

Comment: and what have you attempted?

Comment: I tried to use rownum in listtag but it got generated 100 values. But actual values are 3 only. Unfortunately, I can not share that code.

Please consider it as general solution.

Comment: You might not be able to share proprietary code - though if it doesn't work it's questionable if it is? - but you can include a [mcve] with data and code that replicates what you tried and the problem you had. Your comment suggests the issue is with duplicates - maybe from a join - rather than numbering; what happens if you do a simple listagg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it all within `listagg`, but you can generate the sequential number:

```
select your_column, row_number() over (order by your_column) as rn
from your_table
```

and then use that as an inline view, and concatenate the values together in the `listagg`:

```
select listagg(rn || '. ' || your_column, ' ') within group (order by rn) as result
from (
  select your_column, row_number() over (order by your_column) as rn
  from your_table
)
```

```
RESULT
--------------------
1. ABC 2. DEF 3. GHI
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=92b0ce08a707a55896834d894cd75931)

I've assumed you want them in alphabetic order; if not you can adjust the `row_number()` call.

---

> I tried to use rownum in listtag

That would work too, sort of:

```
select listagg(rownum || '. ' || your_column, ' ') within group (order by rownum) as result
from your_table
```

... but you don't seem to be able to control the ordering, unless you use a subquery anyway - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8bf96d0c9c18c1ff47452a887077371b)

Comment: The alternative (using rownum in an ordered subquery) may be more efficient; the same ordering must be performed either way, and beyond that, `rownum` is always generated, in any query, while analytic functions have some overhead, which in at least some cases is nontrivial.